# tables in Ram or DB tables, for best performances

Tags: java, mysql, xmpp, derby

I am programming a server application (chat server side) with java, which receive requests and send to a target.

1. I have several tables in the database, and *when* the server
   application starts, I programmed it to **copy all the content of the
   database to Map tables (in the ram)** in order to speed up the pull

   - push data while the application running.
     **Dose this correct way? Or you suggest me to pull data from the database directly when I need a detail.** and remove the Map<>
     tables from the ram!?
2. I suffer from memory leak.
3. Does dealing with the database slows the application?

Comment: If you put all data in memory ,the application will not scale for large number of users.Can you be more specific about your application.What features the application need to support? How many users ? How  much data are you expecting? ...

Comment: thanks @skyWalker.... it's chat server based on xmpp with many extras I added, now the number of users 300, and the message payload is a map<key,value> with 12 string field. the application reads message type(custom field) and deal with it by type (20 types) ans pass to the target... UPDATE: memory status at beginig:
total mem ... 21,457,403,904
free mem ... 21,398,745,256
MAX mem ... 32,194,822,144

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether caching all or some of the data in memory makes sense depends on your use case. It can improve performance but it adds complexity which might not be needed.

You can load millions or even billions of records into a JVM, but much more then this you need an off heap storage such as a data store for this purpose or a database. Using off heap memory, you can have trillions of records in a JVM but this is rarely needed.

Comment: I do that and deal with every modification in the data:modify DB and Table in every change.. --- I do that cuz I believe that pull data from RAM is faster than pull data from DB ---. is this true?

Comment: @EsmaeelQash RAM is faster provided you have appropriate indexes and all the data you need is loaded.